# Bootstrap 3 panel-title with header tag (h1) is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using panels and I want the panel title to be larger.  So I read the [bootstrap doc for panel](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-heading) and saw that I could use a `h1.panel-title` inside a `div.panel-header`.  They even give you the markup.  I pasted the markup in my page with h1 and it did not work.

#### HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1 class="panel-title">Panel title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Results:

[image]

I tried using the `lead` class, but it adds a lot of undesirable whitespace underneath it.  If I exclude the `panel-title` class there is too much margin in the `panel-header`.  How do I make this work?

Comment: Is .panel-title overriding the font-size of <h1>? Wouldn't that be a bug in bootstrap code-base?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### New Answer

Thanks for the comment, @ShawnAnderson.  You are absolutely right.  All you need to do is **remove the `panel-title` class** and the h1 will work.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Panel title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29507/

This answer is preferred over my original answer since you do not have to override any bootstrap classes.

### Original Answer

This small amount of css will do the trick if you include it after bootstrap.css.

#### CSS:

```
h1.panel-title {
    font-size: 36px;
}
h2.panel-title {
    font-size: 30px;
}
h3.panel-title {
    font-size: 24px;
}
h4.panel-title {
    font-size: 18px
}
h5.panel-title {
    font-size: 14px
}
h6.panel-title {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

#### Results:

[image]

This works, but I'd like to know if anyone has better ideas.

Comment: That works as well as `.panel-heading h1 { ... }`, unless you want to create your own custom class.

Comment: Just a note, I had to add `!important` in order for the changes to override bootstrap's.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you use the `h1` class instead of the element?  Someone can try it and report back!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Change h3 to h1

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1 class="panel-title">Panel title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: huh? The original post has `<h1 class="panel-title">Panel title</h1>`.